# Как добавить Instagram в список значков в блоке «Поделиться» от Яндекса?

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Как добавить Инстаграм (Instagram) в список значков в [блоке «Поделиться» Яндекса](https://tech.yandex.ru/share/)  (Ya.share2)?

Comment: Добавте больше информации, код.

Answer (score 5):

Яндекс именно потому не добавил значок Instagram в конструктор ya-share2, что постить в Instagram с сайта невозможно.

Единственный способ запостить картинку в Инстаграм - через мобильное приложение. Шарить картинки с сайта в Инстаграм запрещено.

Подробный ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17673156/instagram-share-photo-from-webpage

Документация Instagram по этому поводу: https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

Comment: Ответ правильный (по моему мнению), но не очень понятный. Добавлю от себя. Яндекс именно потому не добавил значок инстаграм в конструктор ya-share2, что постить в Инстаграмм с сайта невозможно. Таким образом, на вопрос "как добавить", ответ - никак.

Comment: Дополнил ответ, хотя и масло масляное получается :) Но согласен, так понятнее, на эту тему где-то была заметка в блоге Яндекса.