# Виджеты соц сетей

Tags: javascript, share, ya-share2

Добрый день! Делаю блок социальных кнопок-иконок соц сетей с помощью https://tech.yandex.ru/share/

Нашёл код для ВК и FB, а инстаграмма нет.. Подскажите, как вписать в код инстаграмм?

Пока прогресс такой:

```
<script src="//yastatic.net/es5-shims/0.0.2/es5-shims.min.js"></script>
<script src="//yastatic.net/share2/share.js"></script>
<div class="ya-share2" data-services="vkontakte,facebook"></div>
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как добавить Instagram в список значков в блоке «Поделиться» от Яндекса?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647424/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-instagram-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b2-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%be%d1%82-%d0%af%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 0):

никак, это противоречит принципам инстаграмма.

вот обсуждения на ту же тему:

- [ru] https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/647464/276190
- [en] https://stackoverflow.com/q/17673156/1470171

А вот что сам инстаграм пишет:
[en] https://www.instagram.com/developer/authorization/

> Note that in order to use these extended permissions, you must first
>   submit your app for review. Here are the scopes we currently support:
>
> basic - to read a user’s profile info and media
>
> public_content - to read any public profile info and media on a user’s
>   behalf (applications no longer accepted)
>
> ...

И далее для всех указано что приложения больше не поддерживаются - (applications no longer accepted). Имеются ввиду **одобренные** инстаграмом приложения.
Соответственно, единственное что можно получить, **если** юзер авторизует на доступ **одобренные** инстраграмом приложение - это **чтение** профиля юзера и его медиа.

Comment: Будет совсем хорошо, если добавите ссылку на эти описание этих принципов.